# How to create pre signed url for DigitalOCean Space using firebase cloud function?

Tags: android, node.js, aws-sdk, digital-ocean, pre-signed-url

I am creating an Android app where users can watch videos. I am using DigitalOcean for hosting the videos and Firebase Realtime Database as the database. I am generating the pre-Signed Url for the video using Firebase callable cloud function when the user clicks to watch the video. I am using AWS SDK for Firebase function to generate the pre-signed URL as I have heard that AWS SDK is compatible with DigitalOCean. But I am unable to get the exact URL. I am getting a URL like following -

```
https://myappvideo.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/video14.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=myAccessKeyId&Content-Type=video%2Fmp4&Expires=1573718047&Signature=Z07GtSybHwbc7m4%2FSczqeYQ%2FwpI%3D&x-amz-acl=public-read&x-amz-server-side-encryption=AES256
```

Here 'myAccessKeyId' is the access key id for my DigitalOcean space. I removed it in this question for security purposes.

When I paste the URL in chrome then it shows the following error-

```
<Error>
 <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
 <RequestId>tx0000000000000bb11173b-005dcd05da-501552-sgp1a</RequestId>
 <HostId>501552-sgp1a-sgp</HostId>
</Error>
```

The Firebase function that I am using is as follows-

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.getS3SignedUrlUpload = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

   const spacesEndpoint = new AWS.Endpoint('https://sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com');

   AWS.config.update({
     endpoint: spacesEndpoint,
     accessKeyId: "MyAccessKeyId",
     secretAccessKey: "MySecretAccessKey",
     signatureVersion: 'v4',
     region: "sgp1" 
   });

   var s3 = new AWS.S3();

   const s3Params = {

     Bucket: "myappvideo", // My DigitalOcean Bucket name
     Key: "video14.mp4",  //The video for which I want to generate pre-signed url
     Expires: 600, // Expires in 10 minutes
     ContentType: "video/mp4",
     ACL: 'public-read',// What is this I don't know, please tell me if you know
     ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256'  // What is this I don't know, please tell me if you know

   };

  return s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params);

});
```

I don't know much about javaScript and writing cloud functions. Please tell me where to make changes to get the correct pre-signed URL for the video.

Comment: The code looks good. I think you want `getObject` not `putObject` as the first param in `getSignedUrl`.

Comment: You may (!?) also need `var s3 = new AWS.S3({ signatureVersion: "v4"});`

Comment: Yes getObject works fine. Can you explain briefly what is the difference between getObject anf putObject ?

Comment: `GET`, `PUT`, `POST` etc. are HTTP verbs and are conventionally (e.g. REST) used to retrieve resources, change existing resources; and create new resources respectively. Retrieving resources (what your browser does when you view a URL) corresponds to `GET` and that's the verb used when you `getObject`. HTH!

Answer (score 0):

SignatureDoesNotMatch means that your upload is not using the same VERB as the command.

your command specifies "putObject"

so the file would need to be uploaded from a form like this

...